# Solution of given equations for $x$ and $y$

Tags: logarithms, systems-of-equations

Solve for $x$ and $y$

$$(2x)^{\log 2}=(3y)^{\log 3}$$

$$3^{\log x}=2^{\log y}$$

Could someone give some hint to approach this question?

Comment: What's the base on the logs?  "$\log$" is ambiguous and the base it refers to (usually 10, $e$, or 2) depends heavily on the level and subject of the source material.

Comment: It is easier to work with products than exponents, so take the log on both sides for both equations.

Comment: Take the $\log$ of everything and solve in the variables $u=\log (x), v=\log (y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\log x = s$, $\log y = t$, and take logs of both sides of the equations.  You get a system of two linear equations in $s$ and $t$.